# Meaning of dog of marvellous wind

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Then, when this dog of **marvellous wind** saw that his foe was dead, he gave him no second glance, but set out at a lope for a farm four miles across the snow where he had left his master when first the wolf was started.

(Ernest Thompson Seton's 'Bingo' <1986>)

---

In above sentence, the wind could be understood as 'a dog with sweeping force' ?

In the dictionary, wind has a meaning of 'any sweeping and destructive force'.

Or are there any other meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**of** indicates a possessive relationship.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine)

[**marvellous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marvelous) (which I think is an old-fashioned spelling, by the way; it's usually *marvelous* these days) simply means "amazing, miraculous, causing wonder".

So the only real question is what **wind** means in this context.  [One meaning of **wind** is *breath*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wind), and it's often used in this sense when referring to exertion - for example, [*to be winded*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/winded) or to be [*out of wind*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Trg4AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22out%20of%20wind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_kfri7djSAhVS52MKHYhxBMo4ChDoAQgvMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22out%20of%20wind%22&f=false) means to be out of breath.

I think that's the most appropriate meaning in this context, because the passage describes a long running fight that goes on over at least one mile, after which the dog immediately begins running again.  So we could paraphrase it as **this dog which was amazingly not winded after this long fight**.

Answer (score 1):

That's an awkward phrase as it is, but without any extra context, I would interpret it to mean that the dog was running by his foe when he noticed it was dead. I say that because I think the author was trying to say that the wind the dog was picking up was substantial, and as the phrase, "he gave him no second glance" indicates, he wasn't slowing down anytime soon.

Comment: If you look up the book, it pretty clearly doesn't mean that the dog was running by his foe when he noticed it was dead: "After a few seconds the whirl of struggling animals resolved itself into a wolf, on his back, with a bleeding collie gripping his throat, and it was now easy for me to step up and end the fight by putting a ball through the wolf's head."